# What's the meaning of order in a django request processing?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

**OVERVIEW**

Consider the below urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import re_path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

a)
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

# b)
# urlpatterns = [
#     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
# ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

print(urlpatterns)
```

As you can see we got 2 url lists, whose `__str__` representation is:

```
a) [<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (admin:admin) 'admin/'>]
b) [<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (admin:admin) 'admin/'>, <URLPattern '^media\/(?P<path>.*)$'>]
```

**PROBLEM**

If I make the same request to `localhost:8000` it's producing 2 different outcomes for the abovementioned url lists:

- Using a) , I'll get a 200 response:

[image]

- Using b) , I'll get a 404 response:

[image]

**QUESTION**

After reading the section ["How django processes a request"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/) I've observed it says in point 3):

> Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first
>   one that matches the requested URL.

What does the concept of "order" means in this context?

For instance, let me put you an analogy of what I understand of "order processing", if i declare a couple of lists (b is extended from a), `a=[0,1,2,3]; b=a+[4,5,6]` and then i do `a.index(2)=2, b.index(2)=2`, that type of order processing (linear search) is what i'd also expect in django.

So I'm failing miserably to understand how the request is processed in the exposed case. For instance, I'd expect the same match in b) than in a) (ie: same response 200 in b) than in a) )

So, could anyone please explain me how this particular request is processed in both cases and why in a) is matching while in b) is not? Also, it'd be helpful to know how to print somehow the order of url attempts even if the response is 200 so one could learn much better about this important topic.

Btw, reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#static didn't clarify too much about this doubt neither.

Comment: I can't at all understand what you're asking here. The word "order" is used in its plain English meaning: Django goes through the patterns *in order* to find one that matches, and stops when it does. This problem has nothing to do with "order" at all, but with the fact that you simply haven't defined a URL that matches the root path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access `http://localhost:8000/`, but at the moment there aren't any matching URL patterns for that. You one URL pattern is for the Django admin, which you can access at `http://localhost:8000/admin/`.

When Django doesn't find a matching URL pattern and you have `DEBUG = True` in your settings, then you get the yellow 'Page Not Found' page.

There are a couple of [hardcoded exceptions](https://github.com/django/django/blob/6fd6d8383f48ea2fe4e058725fa30529a083e9a5/django/views/debug.py#L467). When the URL config is empty, or it has not been modified yet, then you get the "Congratulations it worked" page (your example A).

In your example B, you have modified the `urlpatterns` by adding `static()` to it. Therefore you get the regular yellow 'Page Not Found' page.

In order for `http://localhost:8000/` to work, you need to add a matching URL pattern, for example:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def home_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('home')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_view),
]
```

Note that putting a view in your `urls.py` like this is not good practice. I've done it in this case so that you can quickly add a matching pattern for testing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it makes more sense now, before accepting your answer, do you have any idea about my other question, ie: is it possible to print django attempts like the one see in debug mode so i know which urls django has tried? I mean, I'd like to see where the main url routing code is living, i've tried reading a bit in the django.url folder but i don't see the routing algorithms anyway, thx, +1 in the meantime :D

Comment: [`django.urls.resolve`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/urls/base.py#L21) is the method that takes a url and returns the matching view, args and kwargs. However, you certainly don't need to understand this code in order to use Django. I think you'd need to add printing to that module. However I don't see the need to do that when the yellow debug page shows you that info.

Comment: Yeah, the yellow debug page is certainly a really useful one, but I'd like to understand as well how many urls have been processed in case a match has been found till the url resolving becomes 2nd nature to me, btw, is  `django.urls.resolve` being called by a main routing algorithm? Or it's already the main routing algorithm per-se? You got a point there but i'm one of those strange creatures i like to know how things work internally ;D

Comment: I was wrong, Django doesn’t actually call `resolve` when it is handling the request. Start [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d13a9e44ded4e93570c6ba42ec84e45ddca2505b/django/core/handlers/base.py#L98) if you want to dive into the code.